# MySQL UPDATE issue

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've got an update statement that won't seem to work out for some reason.

```
else if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
  $query = "UPDATE assignments 
               SET expdate = '$expdate', 
                   dispdate = '$dispdate', 
                   duedate = '$duedate', 
                   name = '$name', 
                   cat1 = '$cat1', 
                   cat2 = '$cat2', 
                   cat3 = '$cat3', 
                   schoolid = '$schoolid', 
                   classid = '$classid', 
                   public = '$public', 
                   tags = '$tags', 
                   description = '$description', 
                   symbol = '$symbol' 
             WHERE id = '$assignmentid' 
               AND teacherid = '$uid'";
  echo $query;
  mysql_query($query);
}
```

I've tried much but can't seem to get it to update the row. I know that the function is executing though because `echo $query;` outputs the query.

The specific string after variables are parsed is:

```
UPDATE assignments 
   SET expdate = '1325401200', 
       dispdate = '1293865200', 
       duedate = '1325401200', 
       name = 'Test 7', 
       cat1 = '138', 
       cat2 = '0', 
       cat3 = '0', 
       schoolid = '1', 
       classid = '33', 
       public = '1', 
       tags = 'New Vista High School,,80302,Patrick,Turmala,Test 7,,,138,No sub-categories,No sub-categories,test7,2012,testNew Vista High School,,80302,Patrick,Turmala,Test 7,,,138,0,0,teste,2012,testes', 
       description = 'Test 7', 
       symbol='teste' 
 WHERE id = '21' 
   AND teacherid = '538'
```

Is it a syntax error? What is going on?

Thanks to anyone.

Comment: Are you sure the row has id of 21 and teacherid of 538?

Comment: echo `mysql_error()` after `mysql_query()`. If it's a syntax error, it will become plain.

Comment: Also, are your three date columns MySQL DATETIME types, or are they INTs accepting UNIX timestamps from PHP?

Comment: I assume is no records with id='21' AND teacherid='538' in `assignments` table

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
UPDATE assignments set `fieldname`= values where ...
```

and echo mysql_error to see the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly because there is Mysql Reserved Words in your query like <del>**public**</del>,
You should use **`** to quote that.

Edit: public is not mysql reserved word, try `mysql_error()` to see the error msg.

Comment: `public` is not a reserved keyword: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you let me know the error / exception what you are getting.

I thought of that there is a problem in length of the column. The length for column tags is too short to hold the given value.